# Using Pool<> class in libGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

How and why would one use the [Pool](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html) in libGDX? There is nothing on the official development guide about this class, except for it being used in some examples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [Pool](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html) class is an optimization to avoid garbage collection overhead.  The downside is that one must manually manage the objects in a pool (you must remember to release them so they can be reused), and your objects must be reusable (generally no `final` fields, for example).

Within libGDX, the `Pool` class is used for objects that would otherwise be allocated on each frame (like Actions and Events).

You can ignore the Pool for your own code until you run into problems with too much garbage being generated.

#### How to Use Pool

A `Pool<>` manages a single type of object, so it is parameterized by that type. Objects are taken from a specific `Pool` instance by invoking `obtain` and then should be returned to the Pool by invoking `free`.   The objects in the pool may optionally implement the [`Pool.Poolable`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.Poolable.html) interface (which just requires a `reset()` method be present), in which case the `Pool` will automatically reset the objects when they are returned to the pool.  Objects are initially allocated on demand (so if you never invoke `obtain`, the Pool will contain no objects).

You must implement your own subclass of `Pool<>` because the `newObject` method is abstract.

#### Pool Caveats

Beware of leaking references to Pooled objects.  Just because you invoke "free" on the Pool does not invalidate any outstanding references.  This can lead to subtle bugs if you're not careful.  You can also create subtle bugs if the state of your objects is not fully reset when the object is put in the pool.

Comment: But when i do need them,how will i implement them?

Comment: To implement them, take a look at the demo code that comes with libgdx, or at libgdx itself. I know for a fact that Very Angry Robots uses pools, as does the Stage class. You don't _need_ pools, but, as P.T. says, you might want to consider them if you're allocating objects on each frame.